# Keep timezone information when formatting a date with `Intl`

Tags: javascript, react-native, datetime, timezone

I'm using [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) to format a timestamp into human readable text.

Consider the following timestamp:

```
const timestamp = "2020-11-21T09:17:00-08:00"
```

It includes the timezone information `-08:00`.

When formatting the timestamp like this:

```
const formattedDateTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    timeZoneName: 'shortOffset'
}).format(new Date(timestamp))

console.log(formattedDateTime)
```

I'm seeing the result as:

```
21 November 2020, 18:17 GMT+1
```

I'm currently located in timezone GMT+1. So that makes sense, it's displaying the time in my local timezone.

**Is there a way to get `Intl` to format the date in the timezone specified in the timestamp?**

The result should be:

```
21 November 2020, 09:17 UTC-8
```

All I've found so far, is that we can use the [`timeZone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#timezone) option. But this doesn't seem to work for me. When specifying `timeZone: 'UTC-8'` I'm getting a crash, saying "Invalid time zone UTC-8". Same is the case when using timezone: `UTC-08:00`, `-08:00` and `-8`

Comment: once interpreted as a date, it becomes a js date object, with the conversion to utc time and the time zone information is no longer useful, it cannot be restored. you must keep it separate for later display calculation

Comment: Strictly, -08:00 is an offset. A timezone is a somewhat more complex concept that can have different meanings, e.g. the standard (non DST) timezones that divide the globe into fixed offsets (mostly multiples of 1 hour but not always and mostly aligned with lines of longitude, but not always), and IANA timezones that are contiguous areas that have historically observed the same offsets for local mean solar, standard and daylight saving times and are identified by a representative location. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Per [ECMA-402](https://402.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-isvalidtimezonename), the *timeZone* option only accepts valid IANA representative locations. For a fixed offset of -08:00, the area "Etc" and location "GMT+8" (i.e. "Etc/GMT+8") can be used. Note the reversed sign of the offset (to comply with POSIX style for some reason).

Only whole hour offsets seem to be supported with this notation. While +5:30 is a valid offset, setting the *timeZone* option to "Etc/GMT-530" throws a range error: invalid timeZone option (tested in Safari, Firefox and Chrome).

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('en', {
  timeZone: 'Etc/GMT+8',
  timeZoneName: 'long'
}));
```